# What does “though less so ~” mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, books

I’m reading a book about world history, and there is a phrase in a paragraph I have no idea:

“They were mostly connected to productive hinterlands, **though less so** in the case of Perth than the others.”

This paragraph is talking about colonial capitals in Australia. I couldn’t find any good explanation for the phrase “though less so”, so I hope I can get it and read on.

Comment: have you looked up the meanings of the words, or made other efforts to determine the meaning of the phrase? Would you be equally puzzled by the phrase 'more so'?

Comment: @Spagirl I have, but the way I looked up was wrong. Maybe I was so confused. Now I know how to approach this kind of problem. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "**to a lesser degree** in the case of Perth than the others"

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. It’s all clear now. Thank you again.